# Set product prices based on a range of their dimensions (area) in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, area, price

I use WordPress and woocommerce for an eCommerce website.
I would like to calculate dynamically the product according to its area(height X Width)

So the product price will be based conditionally on area ranges like:

- if an area is between 1 *(sq.ft.)* to 5 *(sq.ft.)* price is 5$
- if an area is between 6 *(sq.ft.)* to 10 *(sq.ft.)* price is 6$

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code example that will auto calculate the product price based on its area **when product is saved in backend**. *You might have to do some adjustments on area calculation based on your measurements unit settings…*

The code:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'calculate_product_price_based_on_area', 20, 3 );
function calculate_product_price_based_on_area( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    if ( $post->post_type != 'product') return; // Only products

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_product', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

    // Product width and height
    $width  = isset($_POST['_width'])  ? (float) $_POST['_width']  : 0;
    $height = isset($_POST['_height']) ? (float) $_POST['_height'] : 0;

    if( $width > 0 && $height > 0 ){
        // Area calculation from product width and height
        $area = $width * $height;

        // Define the price conditionally based on area
        if( $area > 0 && $area <= 5 ){
            $price = 5;
        } elseif( $area > 5 && $area <= 10 ){
            $price = 6;
        }

        // Update the calculated product price
        if( isset($price) && $price > 0 ){
            // if product is not on sale
            if( $_POST['_sale_price'] != '' ){
                // Update active price
                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', $price );
            }
            // Update regular price
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', $price );
            wc_delete_product_transients( $post_id ); // Update product cache
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.